# Как импортировать библиотеку?

Tags: android, android-studio, lib

[image]

Как мне импортировать библиотеку в студио?
https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/downloads/list
Импортировал библиотеку, но в итоге выходит ошибка, 
не может собраться дальше.

[image]

А также в манифесте afreechart подсвечивается, что не правильный путь.

Хотя он и компилируется, и можно импортировать его классы, но при компиляции выдает ошибку, что error package, что-то типа есть исходные коды, а вот скомпилированные файлы этих классов отсутствуют.

Comment: Покажите gradle файл этого модуля.

Comment: а можно ли в студио как то импортировать библиотеку, не могу найти этот способ

Comment: Можно. Вообще советую воспользоваться другой библиотекой, для графиков. Она более свежая.
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: А есть пример с ним, можно скинуть?

Comment: @andreich а как можно поменять цвет шрифта значений на черный, 
дело в том, что он принимает только цифры,  а какая цифра это черная не понятно.

       mChart.setValueTextColor(0);

ставлю любую цифру она становится прозрачной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для импорта .jar библиотеки в android studio скопируйте файл в папку проекта libs, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши и выберете Add As Library

Comment: импортировать и выбрать вариант показа дерева project